# Iterating over a String to check for a number and printing out the String value if it doesn't have a number

Tags: java

I have set up my function for checking for a number in a String, and printing out that String if it has no numbers, and putting up an error message if it does.  Here is my code:

```
public class NumberFunction 
{
    public boolean containsNbr(String str)
    {
        boolean containsNbr = false;
        if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
        {
            for(char c : str.toCharArray())
            {
                if(containsNbr = Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    System.out.println("Can't contain numbers in the word.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
        }
        return containsNbr;
    }
}



import com.imports.validationexample.function.NumberFunction;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        NumberFunction nf = new NumberFunction();
        System.out.println(nf.containsNbr("bill4"));
    }
}
```

I am trying to get it to print out the result to the console, but the result keeps printing multiple times and prints the boolean value, which I do not want, something like this:

bill4
bill4
bill4
bill4
Can't contain numbers in the word.
true


Why is this happening?  I've tried casting but that hasn't worked out either.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a pen and paper and follow execution.

Comment: Please read this, debug, then come back with a better question: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your FOR loop iterates over each character of the String. If it finds a number, it exits. But do you see what happens if it doesn't find a number?

Answer (score 0):

Well you're assingning the value to `containsNbr`.

```
if(containsNbr = Character.isDigit(c))
```

change that line for:

```
if(Character.isDigit(c)) { //will evaluate if 'c' is a number
    containsNbr = true;
    break;
}
```

Also don't have an `else`, put this after the `for-each` loop:

```
for(char c : str.toCharArray())
    if(Character.isDigit(c)) { //will evaluate if 'c' is a number
        containsNbr = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(containsNbr) {
    System.out.println("Can't contain numbers");
}
else {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

So it will print only once the `str` word instead of **n** times.

You were printing it many times because your `else` was inside the `for-loop`. Taking it out, will solve the issue.

Also convert the function from `boolean` to `void` so you won't print that `true` or `false`  at the end.